# Accept two numbers from the user and remove the common digits among both the numbers and print the numbers after modification

Tags: python

How do I remove the common digits from two int variables?

```py
# Take the Input From the User
first = int(input("first: "))
second = int(input("second: "))
```

```
Example 
Input
  first: 436784
  second: 67912
Output  
  first: 4384
  second: 912
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
first = input("first")
second = input("second")
unique_first = int(''.join([i for i in first if i not in second]))
unique_second = int(''.join([i for i in second if i not in first]))
```

Comment: I think the output is supposed to be an integer, plus the time complexity of your solution is O(2n²), whereas using sets has a time complexity of O(6n). Irrelevant for small instances, however definitely worth considering for larger  instances

Comment: You are correct of course that for large inputs a set is preferable. As we are dealing with inputs, I guessed this is not the case :) 
(Wrote my answer before seeing yours )

Comment: Very true, also very good answer, and definitely more intuitive for a beginner

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `set` to remove the common elements:

```
x=input("Enter number: ")
y=input("Enter number: ")
common=list(set(x).intersection(set(y)))
res=[j for j in x if j not in common]
res2=[j for j in y if j not in common]
print(''.join(res),''.join(res2))
```

Comment: Some micro-optimizations can be done here. Not significant for small inputs, but I still think they are valid; (1) you don't need to convert `y` to a `set` ([`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) accepts any iterable), so `set(x).intersection(y)` is better; (2) no need to convert the resulting set to a list. Actually, `in` and `not in` become faster when `common` is a plain set: `common = set(x).intersection(y)`;

Comment: ... (3) if all you want to do with `res` and `res2` is join them (as is the case), there is no need to construct an intermediary list - you can use [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression): `res = ''.join(j for j in x if j not in common)` (and the same thing for `res2`).

Answer (score 0):

```
a_str = input("first")
b_str = input("second")
a_set = set(a_str)
b_set = set(b_str)
only_a = a_set - b_set
only_b = b_set - a_set

a_final = int("".join([i for i in a_str if i in only_a]))
b_final = int("".join([i for i in b_str if i in only_b]))
```